# Some Axios endpoints get 401 but only in production

Tags: node.js, spring, axios, production, http-status-code-401

We are testing the move from TEST to PROD with out Node.JS / Vue / Axios application. What we have found is that 90% of it works just fine, but three calls to the server endpoints get a 401 error. This does not happen in NPM test mode, where it works just fine. The three endpoints are POST calls (they are not the only ones) and return a file (PDF, JPG or ZIP). That is the only thing that they have in common.

The backend is a Spring Boot/Java application that exposes a number of API calls. Most processing and all data storage happens on the server. We have handled all the CORS issues, so that is not a problem.

The issue occurs only if we run the node application in production mode. That is, we compile it with npm build, and then expose the build via some form of server. We have tried an Apache website, a docker container, and the serve feature referred to in the node build documentation.

The back end normally runs as a docker container, but we have tried this interactively under Eclipse, and run the built jar without the docker container. This has made no difference.

In the Spring boot, it is returning a StreamingResourceBody

```
@PostMapping(value="getZippedDocs", produces="application/zip")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> getZippedDocs(
  ServletOutputStream responseOutputStream, 
    @RequestParam(name = "userid") Long userid,
    @RequestBody MyObject x) { 
  log.debug("Generate Zip of docs for id = {}", x.getId()); 
  String fileName = "X-"+ x.getId() +"_documents.zip";
  return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .header("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + ".zip\"")
    .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/zip"))
    .body(out -> myeService.getZippedDocs(userid, x, responseOutputStream));
}
```

The node function that handles this is:

```
function getDocumentZip() {
    let config = {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + store.state.token,
            'Accept': 'application/zip'
        }
    };

    const userid = store.state.person.id
    const claim = store.state.claim;
    const url = baseurl + "demurrage/getZippedDocs" + "?userid=" + userid;
    const zipfileName = "Claim-" + claim.id + ".zip"

    store.dispatch("loading", true)
    axios.post(url, claim, config)
        .then((response) => {
            const blob = new Blob([response.data], {
                type: "application/zip",
            });
            const data = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            var link = document.createElement('a')
            link.setAttribute('href', URL)
            link.setAttribute("download", zipfileName);
            link.href = data
            document.body.appendChild(link);

            link.click()
            document.body.removeChild(link);
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blob)

            store.dispatch("loading", false);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
            store.dispatch("loading", false);
        })
}
```

As I say, in NPM development mode, this works just sweet and dandy. But in production, we get a 401. If I copy the URL that has failed from the Chrome Inspector, and run that through a curl command, it works as expected.

Any clues at all would be appreciated - spent 3 days on this now and getting no where.

Answer (score 0):

It transpired that Auth0 had blocked our M2M tokens, hence why they were not authorising correctly. The App doesn't need them really, and Spring has this part commented out for present, but Apache does care!